# Qual a forma de armazenar um gráfico como uma variável e exporta-la depois?

Tags: r, plot

Considerando:

```
x<-1:10
y<-10:1
plot(x,y)
```

[image: Gráfico XY]

Gostaria de armazenar o resultado de `plot()` em uma variável, como

```
grafico<-plot(x,y)
```

é possível?
E para exportar como faço?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu recomendaria utilizar ou o `ggplot2` ou o `lattice`, ambos funcionam de forma que os gráficos são objetos do R, que podem ser modificados, salvos etc de maneira fácil.  Por exemplo:

```
library(ggplot2)
grafico_ggplot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point()
grafico_ggplot

library(lattice)
grafico_lattice <- xyplot(cyl~mpg, mtcars)
grafico_lattice
```

Entretanto, caso você queira fazer com o gráfico base do R, você pode usar a função `recordPlot`:

```
plot(1:10)
grafico <- recordPlot()
dev.off()
grafico
```

É possível, ainda, transformar os gráficos base em gráficos `grid`, o que te permite maior flexibilidade em alterar os elementos dos gráficos e combiná-los com gráficos do `ggplot2` e `lattice`. Para isso você tem que utilizar o pacote `gridGraphics` que transforma gráficos base em gráficos `grid`:

```
library(gridGraphics)
plot(1:10)
grid.echo()
grafico_grid <-  grid.grab()
grid.draw(grafico_grid)
```

Answer (score 3):

Você deve usar o recordPlot para isso. Veja como:

```
x<-1:10
y<-10:1
plot(x,y)
grafico <- recordPlot()
plot.new()
grafico
```

O intuito do recordPlot é exatamente o que o próprio nome diz. Guardar o resultado de um plot em uma variável para depois plotá-lo novamente. A linha **plot.new()** cria ou inicia um novo frame para que o gráfico seja plotado. Ao chamar **grafico** (ultima linha) o gráfico é plotado novamente.